# Is it possible to include virtual files from the main domain in a subdomain in asp?

Tags: asp-classic, include, subdomain

The main domain includes a virtual file like this:

`<!--#include virtual="/includes/functions/index.asp"-->`

That in turn includes a whole bunch of function files, something like this:

```
<!--#include virtual="/includes/function/includedfunctionone.asp"-->
<!--#include virtual="/includes/function/includedfunctiontwo.asp"-->
<!--#include virtual="/includes/function/includedfunctionthree.asp"-->
```

But when I try to include these from a subdomain, they can't be found.  I presume because the server is searching for the `/includes/functions/index.asp` within the subdomain itself.

I can access the **main** include from the subdomain changing it to a relative path:

`<!--#include file="../includes/functions/index.asp"-->`

However, that breaks when the main file calls the list of nested virtual includes. And I don't want to change all of those to `#include file`, because they need to be absolute paths.

**What I've Tried 1**

I have tried using a full server path like this:

`D:\domains\website.com\wwwroot\includes\functions\index.asp`

... but that gives me  `'ASP 0126' Include file not found`

**What I've Tried 2**

I've also tried including a full url, like this:

`http://website.com/includes/functions/index.asp`

... but that gives me a fat bold 500 error with no indication of the specific error.

Comment: Have you tried virtual directories, (ie have one folder as a virtual directory of more than one site)?

Comment: No I haven't, I'll look into that and give it a go, thank you :)

Comment: See this page - scroll down to "The Virtual Keyword" http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_incfiles.asp

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox What version of `OS` / `IIS` are your using?

Comment: To everybody who helped, I'm very sorry for not getting back sooner, something urgent came up and I forgot all about this. @John - the virtual directories worked a treat and thanks for the link.  If you can put it into an answer I'll mark it as the one. For the record we're on  Win Server 2008 and IIS 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my comment as an answer.

In IIS manager, setup the folder containing your includes as a virtual directory of each website where you need to use it - then you can use

```
<!--#include virtual="/YourVirtualDirectory/YourInclude.asp"-->
```

[More details here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_incfiles.asp) - Scroll down to "The Virtual Keyword"

Answer (score 0):

I hope that will help you...
This works for me with the subdomain folder in the main folder of the website.

Step 0 : Make sure that you can access the relative parent folder path using your scripts
(IIS > Website Properties > Base folder > Configuration Button > Options tab > Check if not checked)

On your subdomain you can try this script :

Step 1 : Get the content of your asp functions file

```
Dim Fso : Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim File : Set File = Fso.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("../PathOfYourFuncFile.asp"), 1)
Dim FileContent : FileContent = File.ReadAll
File.Close
Set File = Nothing
```

Step 2 : Clear <% and %> in FileContent variable

```
FileContent = Replace(FileContent, "<", "")
FileContent = Replace(FileContent, ">", "")
FileContent = Replace(FileContent, "%", "")
```

Step 3 : Use the script in your current page

```
Execute FileContent
```

Step 4 : Try to call your functions and subs

If that works you can easily optimise the script to get a clear code.
(Sorry for my bad english)

**Edit :**

this will not corrupt html content returned by functions or subs. Files loaded have to be only asp not html content with asp scripts inside.

```
Function StreamReader(vFic, vCharset)

    Dim oContent
    Dim oStreamReader : Set oStreamReader = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With oStreamReader
        .Open
        .Charset = vCharset
        .LoadFromFile vFic
        oContent = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With
    Set oStreamReader = Nothing

    StreamReader = oContent
End Function

FileContent = StreamReader(Server.MapPath("File2.asp"), "utf-8")
FileContent = Replace(FileContent, Chr(Asc("<")) & Chr(Asc("%")), "")
FileContent = Replace(FileContent, Chr(Asc("%")) & Chr(Asc(">")), "")

Execute FileContent
```

Comment: All that just to use a include that is easily accessible with a `Virtual Directory` mapping into the sub domain site?

Comment: Also you do realise that any HTML in a `response.write` or string variable will be corrupted by those statements (at least the first 2).